# Cannot Insert data from button press with razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I am currently displaying information from a table called Workout table but what I want to do is take the WorkoutId then from another table the userId and save them in a table called UserCompletedWorkouts.

Here is what i already have:

view

```
@model IEnumerable<SportsCoach.Models.WorkoutModel>
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Workout";
ViewBag.PageName = "View workout";
}
<section id="MainContent" class="container">
<h2>Workouts</h2>
<p>This page can be used to add, edit, view and delete workouts. </p>


<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th>Day</th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.WorkoutDetails)

        </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {

        <tr>
            <td>
                <b>@Html.Raw(item.Day)</b>
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.Raw(item.WorkoutDetails).Replace("\n", "<br />")<br />
                @Html.ActionLink("Confirm workout", "Create", null, new { @class = "btn btn-primary col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

Comment: On a side note, You don't need to do the `HtmlEncode` and then use `Html.Raw`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything that involves inserting or editing data should remain within the controller. The purpose of the View is to simply display the result of all the behind the scenes logic.

What you would have to do, assuming you have the WorkoutID from the Model in that view is create another function called `SaveCompletedWorkout`

In the view you posted, you would need to create a link for it inside the loop. Ex:

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Controller","CompleteWorkout",new { WorkoutId = item.WorkoutId })
```

As for the function to save the item:

```
 public ActionResult CompleteWorkout(int workoutId)
    {
        //Do checking to make sure workoutid is valid
        //Database.UserCompletedWorkouts.Add(new UserCompletedWorkout() { UserId = User.Id, WorkoutID = workoutID });


        //Return a view of whatever now
        return View();
    }
```

Edit: Also, theres no need to encode and use Raw, simply use

```
<td>@item.WorkoutDetails @Html.ActionLink(...)</td>
```

Comment: You can close it by clicking the checkmark at the top left of the answer.